# ValueError: cannot insert Cluster Labels, already exists

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cluster-analysis

[Screenshot of Code here][1]

## Cluster Neighborhoods using k-means.#

Not sure why it isnt workon this notebook. Worked previously.

```
# set number of clusters

kclusters = 5

toronto_grouped_clustering = toronto_grouped.drop('Neighborhood', 1)

# run k-means clustering

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=kclusters, random_state=0).fit(toronto_grouped_clustering)

# check cluster labels generated for each row in the dataframe

kmeans.labels_[0:10]
```

output : array[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

## add clustering labels

```
neighborhoods_venues_sorted.insert(0, 'Cluster Labels', kmeans.labels_)

toronto_merged = toronto_data

# merge toronto_grouped with toronto_data to add latitude/longitude for each neighborhood

toronto_merged = toronto_merged.join(neighborhoods_venues_sorted.set_index('Neighborhood'), on='Neighbourhood')

toronto_merged.head() # check the last columns!
```

Value error:

```
ValueError                                
<ipython-input-115-a141136032c2> in <module>
 1 # add clustering labels
----> 2 neighborhoods_venues_sorted.insert(0, 'Cluster Labels', kmeans.labels_)
      3 
      4 toronto_merged = toronto_data
      5 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in insert(self, loc, column, value, allow_duplicates)
   3494         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
   3495         value = self._sanitize_column(column, value, broadcast=False)
-> 3496         self._data.insert(loc, column, value, allow_duplicates=allow_duplicates)
   3497 
   3498     def assign(self, **kwargs) -> "DataFrame":

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in insert(self, loc, item, value, allow_duplicates)
   1171         if not allow_duplicates and item in self.items:
   1172             # Should this be a different kind of error??
-> 1173             raise ValueError(f"cannot insert {item}, already exists")
   1174 
   1175         if not isinstance(loc, int):

ValueError: cannot insert Cluster Labels, already exists
```

Comment: Please include the code in the post!

Comment: Sorry about that - first post :). I included the code in a screenshot attached.

Comment: I forgive you, but you should paste it here and format it correctly. Screenshots are no good!

Comment: Done! Hopefully this can provide more insight.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't insert 'Cluster Labels' column into the table as it already exists there.

You should drop the column first by

```
neighborhoods_venues_sorted.drop(['Cluster Labels'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

after that you may re-run your code

```
neighborhoods_venues_sorted.insert(0, 'Cluster Labels', kmeans.labels_)
```